# Unbounded parameter counts in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'd like to be able to process parameters of the form `&paramN` where N is a positive integer with [AngularUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/) and [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). So for example:

`http://thingy.com/app/?param1=foo&param42=towel&param3021414=fubar`

I've read the angular documentation on setting up controllers [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) but I don't see any way to do this - regex only seems to work on the url path, not the params. Is this possible?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. The link you have provided is about Angular UI, not Angular.

Comment: UI-router supports [query parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters) as well

Comment: @zeroflagL yes, I'm using AngularUI and ui-router. Sorry for the lack of specificity, I'm just getting started with AngularX and hacking on other people's code, so I'm not quite familiar with which portions of the software cover which features.

Comment: @NewDev The question isn't just supporting query parameters, it's supporting a unbounded list of query parateters of the form `param\d+`.

Comment: What is the meaning of the number, if I may ask? I've got the feeling that `paramN` isn't the best choice anyway.

Comment: @zeroflagL I need to pass a theoretically unbounded list of tuples to the application. I considered 1) passing a single parameter with semicolons and commas separating the tuples and tuple elements, 2) one parameter for each element in the tuple with elements separated by semicolons, and 3) the approach above where each tuple gets a set of parameters, e.g. &foo1=42&bar1=baz&foo2=.... The latter seemed the least filthy out of the three.

Comment: A common way to achieve this is to simply add the parameter more than once: `param=foo&param=towel&param=fubar`. A framework might additionally require the usage of brackets: `param[]=foo&param[]=towel&param[]=fubar`. In any case the framework should create a `param` array. I don't know if Angular or ui-router support this. A large number of parameters may also be a sign of a wrong design choice. A POST request, for instance, might be a better alternative. But that depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could ui-router as New Dev said in the comments, but I believe that you are [looking to access the $routeParams provider.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

That should give you access to the parameters that you have defined (use the `$route.current.params` as specified in the link if you are having trouble with $routeParams).

Comment: I've clarified the question quite a bit in the OP comments, but to repeat here, I am using ui-router. The question is how to specify an unlimited list of parameters of the form `param\d+` in the $stateProvider url.